# SSIS - How to apply replace function on all text columns in data flow

Tags: sql-server, csv, replace, ssis

I have a data flow with over 150 columns and many of them are of data type string, I need to remove comma's and double quotes from the value of every text column because they are causing issues when I export the data to CSV, is there an easy way to do that other than doing it explicitly for every column in a derived column or script compnent?

Comment: where is the source data coming from? is it a DB or a text file?

Comment: what you can do is output to temporary flat file in, say, pipe-delimited format. Then add a new data flow and read the temp file as , for instance, tab-separated (i.e. it will read each row as on as one big column since there are no tabs on it). Then replace all the commas and double quotes with empty strings, then replace the pipes with commas and save.

Comment: @Jayvee, CSV generators will sometimes add double quotes to a column that has a comma in it.  What you say will break that structure and cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Raj, the idea is to generate an intermediate file which format we define,e.g. pipe-delimited and without text qualifier.
Such file can then be read as one unique column per row (we'll read it as tab-separated, for example).
Any commas or double quotes can then be safely removed, because they will be part of the data, not the format. 
As we'll be dealing with only one big column, the replacement can be done in one line within a Derived Column. 
After the unwanted commas and double quotes were eliminated, the file can be output in the required format; e.g. comma-separated by replacing the pipes

Comment: Thanks @Jayvee, that should work for me, the only issue would be is how to assign the values back to the columns in the data flow after you read them as you will read them as one column, but i might not need to do that as i can just replace the tab with a comma and write it to the file directly, I will try this and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to loop through columns in a script component, then i was able to check the column data type and do a replace function, here is the [**post**](http://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/ssis-global-replace-for-all-columns-using-a-script-component/) i used.

Comment: Please, include at least a minimal information about the post. As a bare minimun, the title of the post. SO shpuld be self contained. If the link is broken this answer is completely useless

Answer (score 1):

In the script generator below, put all your column names from the CSV in the order that you want, and run it.

```
;With ColumnList as
(
            Select 1 Id, 'FirstColumn' as ColumnName
    Union   Select 2, 'SecondColumn'
    Union   Select 3, 'ThirdColumn'
    Union   Select 4, 'FourthColumn'
    Union   Select 5, 'FifthColumn'
)
Select 'Trim (Replace (Replace (' + ColumnName + ', '','', ''''), ''"'', ''''))'
From ColumnList
Order BY Id
```

The Id column should contain a proper sequence (I would generate that in EXCEL. Here is the output

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Trim (Replace (Replace (FirstColumn, ',', ''), '"', ''))
Trim (Replace (Replace (SecondColumn, ',', ''), '"', ''))
Trim (Replace (Replace (ThirdColumn, ',', ''), '"', ''))
Trim (Replace (Replace (FourthColumn, ',', ''), '"', ''))
Trim (Replace (Replace (FifthColumn, ',', ''), '"', ''))

(5 row(s) affected)
```

You could just cut and paste from here into your SSIS dataflow.

Comment: This would work but still requires manually identifying text fields then generate the script and add it to the derived column transformation which is what i'm trying to avoid here

Comment: In SSIS, a CSV will default all incoming fields to String 50.